# How to debug ip xfrm rules

Tags: ipsec

I created ip xfrm rules on 2 machine and trying to pass traffic through the ipsec tunnel. The packet comes into the other end, encrypted, and disappears.

I traced them through iptables, and here is the trace.

```
2015-11-27T14:50:21.442638+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.667488] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.442665+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.667513] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:rule:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.442672+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.667580] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.442674+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.667589] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.471390+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.696166] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.471401+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.696184] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:rule:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.471408+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.696225] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.471409+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.696234] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.695777+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.920757] TRACE: raw:PREROUTING:policy:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.695801+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.920804] TRACE: mangle:PREROUTING:rule:2 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.695808+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.920847] TRACE: mangle:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108 
2015-11-27T14:50:21.695810+04:30 cfae kernel: [70234.920875] TRACE: filter:INPUT:policy:1 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=00:0c:29:b7:97:49:00:0c:29:42:5b:e1:08:00 SRC=172.24.1.178 DST=10.60.60.31 LEN=128 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=61 ID=0 DF PROTO=UDP SPT=4500 DPT=4500 LEN=108
```

From the traces, I see that packet is going from filter:INPUT back to raw:PREROUTING, which means it must be going through xfrm lookup/decode processing. But the packet comes out of this processing unchanged (same length, same src/dst addresses).

But "ip -s xfrm state" shows 0 falied/processed packets.

Is there any way I can trace these packets through xfrm module? Or is there a way to enable debugging for xfrm?

Here is the configuration.

```
    On Machine1: 
    # ip xfrm state
    src 10.60.60.31 dst 172.24.1.178
        proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212013014 mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 
        auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xc2dde59416e78c96b9b0333686b3cf0b09016bb1c1d27215d3dbf7aca471304a1c25536eb2648b3dcd8946047007389d06eb3fb4c4e9379630acae51bd755b07 96
        enc cbc(aes) 0x944023fd181e13d401f80e2166654b549b758aeeb9f382a20ca967631b111ef0
        encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 10.60.60.31
        sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    src 172.24.1.178 dst 10.60.60.31
        proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212013014 mode tunnel
        replay-window 0 
        mark 212013014/0xffffffff
        auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xc2dde59416e78c96b9b0333686b3cf0b09016bb1c1d27215d3dbf7aca471304a1c25536eb2648b3dcd8946047007389d06eb3fb4c4e9379630acae51bd755b07 96
        enc cbc(aes) 0x944023fd181e13d401f80e2166654b549b758aeeb9f382a20ca967631b111ef0
        encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 172.24.1.178
        sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    # ip xfrm policy
    src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir fwd priority 65535 
        tmpl src 10.60.60.31 dst 172.24.1.178
            proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212013014 mode tunnel
            level use 
    src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir in priority 65535 
        tmpl src 10.60.60.31 dst 172.24.1.178
            proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212013014 mode tunnel
            level use 
    src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
        dir out priority 65535 
        mark 212013014/0xffffffff
        tmpl src 172.24.1.178 dst 10.60.60.31
            proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212013014 mode tunnel
            level use 


    On Machine2:
    # ip xfrm policy
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir fwd priority 65535 
    tmpl src 172.24.1.178 dst 10.60.60.31
        proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212012972 mode tunnel
        level use 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir in priority 65535 
    tmpl src 172.24.1.178 dst 10.60.60.31
        proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212012972 mode tunnel
        level use 
src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
    dir out priority 65535 
    mark 212012972/0xffffffff
    tmpl src 10.60.60.31 dst 172.24.1.178
        proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212012972 mode tunnel
        level use 
# ip xfrm state
src 172.24.1.178 dst 10.60.60.31
    proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212012972 mode tunnel
    replay-window 0 
    auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xc2dde59416e78c96b9b0333686b3cf0b09016bb1c1d27215d3dbf7aca471304a1c25536eb2648b3dcd8946047007389d06eb3fb4c4e9379630acae51bd755b07 96
    enc cbc(aes) 0x944023fd181e13d401f80e2166654b549b758aeeb9f382a20ca967631b111ef0
    encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 172.24.1.178
    sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0 
src 10.60.60.31 dst 172.24.1.178
    proto esp spi 0x5fca3acb reqid 212012972 mode tunnel
    replay-window 0 
    mark 212012972/0xffffffff
    auth-trunc hmac(sha512) 0xc2dde59416e78c96b9b0333686b3cf0b09016bb1c1d27215d3dbf7aca471304a1c25536eb2648b3dcd8946047007389d06eb3fb4c4e9379630acae51bd755b07 96
    enc cbc(aes) 0x944023fd181e13d401f80e2166654b549b758aeeb9f382a20ca967631b111ef0
    encap type espinudp sport 4500 dport 4500 addr 10.60.60.31
    sel src 0.0.0.0/0 dst 0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: Looking at the ports (UDP/4500) these packets are either IKE messages or UDP encapsulated ESP packets. Neither of them will be processed (again) by the IPsec stack.

Answer (score 6):

To debug xfrm, you can use command `ip xfrm monitor`.

It will show changes in database policy. 
And it will show the processing of each data packets.

Answer (score 1):

http://techblog.newsnow.co.uk/2011/11/simple-udp-esp-encapsulation-nat-t-for.html

It appears that the Linux kernel will not decapsulate the packets without some instruction. We need to bind to a socket on the incoming udp port and enable udp encapsulation.
Above link has the perl script to do it.
After this, my traffic is working without any issues.